# Can I make Windows have multiple passwords for a single user?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, user-accounts

How can I make Windows accept more than one password as the correct password at the logon screen? What registry key do I change, or what setting?

Comment: I am fairly certain the answer is that there's no supported out-of-the-box method for doing this.  I'm not making this an answer because there may be a non-out-of-the-box method for doing this (but I don't know it).

Comment: Just give them the same password and tell them it is their own very special password and that your feelings would be terribly hurt if they changed it.

Comment: edited question.

Comment: It's possible to allow multiple users to share the same profile directory so they share the same desktop, files and settings. But it's extremely tedious to setup. You'd be better off just using different users and setup some privileges to allow them access some shared files.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you would want this?

Comment: @Zoredache does it really matter?  I

Comment: @billc.cn If you post how to do it, I'll consider it an answer.

Comment: It may matter, since your request is unusual.  AFAIK having multiple accounts with the same settings, permissions and environment doesn't really gain you anything.  If you would explain the reasoning behind your requirements , and the reasoning why you came to believe this solution was the right one, perhaps people could provide you more useful assistance or at least provide you alternatives that meet your requirements.

Comment: I believe it is possible with a third-party or custom software (look up GINA and Winlogon).  I know of some software that I believe accepts two or more different responses for the same login prompt / user account, so it should be do-able.  I don't think it is just a settings change though; you'll need to change how accounts are authenticated on a fundamental level.

Comment: I can see this causing **huge** incompatibilities and breaking others . . .

Comment: a possible benefits from such option would be to set the same password at different keyboard leyouts. This can save the double keying every time you type the correct password in the wrong keyboard leyout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that would be possible.  It's probably possible to have two accounts share the same profile though, if you adjust the NTFS permissions appropriately.  If it is possible, it would probably be best to not have the two accounts logged in at the same time.

Comment: they wouldn't be...

Comment: This answer is incomplete and a comment at best.  Without detail instructions how to achieve this, this answer, isn't really helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

**No, this is not possible under Windows**. For each user a single spot is reserved for the password hash of each user in the SAM database.

Under Windows 10 you can also assign a PIN to a user which can be used to log on locally to the machine, effectively giving you a second password that that purpose only.