# Windows 7 admin user has password, but prompts "create password"

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, user-accounts

I have a fresh install of Windows 7, and during the setup phase it asked me to pick a password. I use this password every time I start the computer.

I would now like to change that password.

However when I view my administrator-level user, the change password prompt instead says "create password".

I really don't want to end up in a situation where I have two (possibly different) passwords to maintain.

What is going on? How can I change the existing password?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug, or you might be selecting wrong user. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to change password of currently logged user. It is not possible that you will have second password. Worst case scenario, you just won't change it. You should assume that by creating password you will change existing one to created one.

> For each user a single spot is reserved for the password hash of each user in the SAM database.

Taken from [Can I make Windows have multiple passwords for a single user?](https://superuser.com/a/1106781/399064) by [Peter Hahndorf](https://superuser.com/users/3719/peter-hahndorf).

*Warning*: If you are using EFS (encrypted file system - you ticked:

[image: Encrypt contents to secure data]

somewhere), you might want to [backup this certificate](https://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=17570) beffore attempting to set this password (in most cases this won't be required).